# Include module with class and have class' path resolve to where the module is included in

Tags: ruby

I have the following example:

```
module A
  class B
  end
end

module C
  include A
end

C.constants
#=> [:B]

C::B
#=> A::B
```

Is there a way to make `C::B` really resolve to `C::B` and not `A::B`, since the `B` class is now included in module `A`?

Comment: Yes and no. `A::B` and `C::B` refer to the same object. Inspecting a module (or class) prints the module's `name` which is set when the module is assigned to a constant for the first time.

Comment: The problem is that I have an engine which looks for a `C::B` but it doesn't find it, since the name is set to `A::B`. Is there a straight-forward way to change this name, without going the "ugly" way?

Comment: That contradicts your above example – `C::B` apparently returns the class just fine. Could you show the engine's code to look up the class?

Comment: It's a custom fork of Ruote; I believe it uses the exact name, which resolves to `A::B`, that's why it fails to find my class. But I didn't necessarily ask regarding Ruote, my question was in general, on how (or whether) is it possible to change the name to which a constant resolves to.

Comment: Constants refer to objects and multiple constants (and variables, too) may refer to the same object. The constant doesn't have a `name` attribute, the object it refers to (your class) has one. Changing a module's `name` attribute does not alter namespacing or Ruby's constant lookup. It's just a string. Typing `C::B` in IRB invokes `inspect` which in turn calls `to_s`, which returns `"A::B"`.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. Then it must be something more involved that Ruote is doing, leading to the inability to find the class in the new scope. I'll investigate further. Thanks!